# Is [0] equivelate to a space, and does the fact there is one part in different brackets matter?

Tags: javascript

```
var _$_f307 = ["className","animation-window","getElementsByClassName","body","animation-window animate","bl45","st.0ff","!!!","innerHTML","rocket-code";] 

document[_$_f307[3]][_$_f307[2]](_$_f307[1])[0][_$_f307[0]] = _$_f307[4];
```

Comment: Doesn't the code look stupid to you too? Why would someone ever want to write something like that?

Comment: @baao pretty sure this question is about understanding a given minified, compressed or obfuscated code.

Answer (score 1):

The given code sample is probably the result of code minification or obfuscation. To understand such code, it is a good idea to transform it into something more readable by replacing cryptic identifiers such as `_$_f307[3]` with their values, here `"body"`:

```
document["body"]["getElementsByClassName"]("animation-window")[0]["className"] = "animation-window animate";
```

This is still a bit unreadable, so you could replace the bracket notation for property access with dot notation:

```
document.body.getElementsByClassName("animation-window")[0].className = "animation-window animate";
```

That's it, a readable line of JavaScript code which changes the CSS class of the first HTML element having class "animation-window". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className for details.

PS: `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array and `[0]` returns the first value of that array. Most often, checking the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) helps you to quickly find answers to such questions.

Comment: Thanks, the dot thing definitely helped.